# Tackle needed for basic fishing in Miami?

Tags: united-states, fishing, fishing-tackle, fishing-rods

I have just purchased a 6' light action Shakespeare Ugly Stik GX2 spinning rod and a 3000 size Penn Pursuit 2 reel. I also have some 8lb test mono line. I live near Miami Beach, Florida and will be fishing Saltwater/freshwater from piers and over canals/rivers.

I don't have any idea about the types of fish that are down here and so I am not really sure what kind of tackle I should use. What hook sizes are best and in general what kind of tackle should I be using? I am not really going for any particular type of fish, just trying to have fun. If someone knows about fish down here and could give me tips on that it would be great too!

Comment: While I hope that you will get the answers you want on here, I would advise you to visit your piers and canals/rivers during busy hours, and chat up some locals. I also would recommend youtube, there are many youtubers around that area, and you could get an idea of spots, species, and gear. Your local tackle shop will also have some great recommendations and could hook you up (he he) with the proper gear. Good luck and tight lines!

Comment: @Peter1807 good point, I will do that. Most of the tackle shops near me only speak Spanish and are more for boaters fishing but I will talk to people on the piers.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say that I suspect that you will soon find the gear you have to be a bit light for the fish you are likely to encounter from piers and other saltwater locations. 8lb test can nominally lift 8lbs - before it starts to degrade from the sun, exposure, nicks from rocks, etc. Though you can fight heavier fish on light lines, that really only works where you can let the fish run. In a pier situation you'd run into the problem of the fish getting into the pilings and having the line cut by barnacles or the concrete. Fishing for bass in the canal is a different story.

Comment: @That Idiot ok that's a good point too. But couldn't I just use higher lb braided line with the same rod for bigger fish? I read somewhere that although not ideally, my rod can handle a 35lb fish. I got a light rod because I know most of the time I will be catching smaller fish and I want to enjoy the fight.

Comment: @NULL - You are absolutely right. Some 30lb braids have the diameter of 8lb mono. The line is my biggest concern. And in open water you could land virtually any size fish on a light rod with enough line (and a reel with a drag that doesn't catch fire as line is ripping out). One other concern is that the lighter rod won't have the backbone to control a larger fish to keep it out of structure. But honestly, if you get the line sorted out you should be fine. And if you aren't, you'll have a great story.